# 3-socket replacement extension cord end?

Tags: electrical, extension-cord

I have an extension cord on a retractable reel, and it has a molded-on end with three sockets, like this:

[image: extension cord female end]

Unfortunately, the quality of the sockets isn't great -- at least a couple of them are quite loose and don't make a reliable connection when things are plugged in. I'd like to replace the existing end with a better one. There are plenty of good single-socket replacements like this:

[image: replacement end]

I'd really like to keep the ability to plug in several things at the same time, but I can't find a 3-socket replacement end. **Do aftermarket 3-socket cord ends even exist?**

Comment: You could put on a single socket and just plug in a 3-in-1 like https://amzn.to/2Shr6SV

Comment: @manassehkatz If the 3-socket end doesn't exist, that might be the only option. It's not as nice as having it attached, though.

Comment: they have something like that at dollar tree; a tiny "power strip" w/3 grounded outlets; just lop off the plug and wire into your cord.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is one of the places where code and consumer parts don't match. I have tried in several cases to make code approved triplex adapters , even as a licensed electrician, I cannot do it legally , even with listed parts, I have asked several major mfg of cord caps for a way many years ago, because what you ask is reasonable, but in my state there is no way to do it because there are no listed "cord caps" with 3 outlets but it would make them $ if there were in my opinion. At this time I have not found a listed model to do what we both and many others want.

Comment: Thanks for confirming that the part I'm looking for just doesn't seem to be available. I thought it might be easier to find if I knew the right name, but since you've already looked I won't keep at it.

Answer (score 4):

Have you considered adding a duplex outlet in a metal box like a (RACO 1-Gang Gray Metal Interior New Work/Old Work Standard). You could even upgrade to a quad outlet set-up. You would need the box, an outlet, face plate and strain relief where the cord enters the box.  Just remember to not exceed the amperage rating of the cord or circuit breaker. The extra outlets are for the convenience of not having to plug and unplug devices.

Comment: You'll also need to strain-relief the cord where it enters the box

Comment: I should have added  that to the list, plus the outlets and a face plate

Comment: You still should. :)

Comment: I was about to ask about this, thanks for answering!

Comment: While you're at it, you can put a GFCI in that box. A portable GFCI is a useful thing to have in any case.